# Stale Messages in INT_MESSAGE table Spring Integration Aggregator

Tags: spring, spring-integration, aggregator

we have been using spring integration aggregator (version 5.1.4.RELEASE) in our project with the following configuration

```
<int:aggregator id="adobeJdbcAggregator" input-channel="aggregatorInputChannel" 
                                             output-channel="aggregatorOutputChannel"
                                             correlation-strategy-expression="headers['eventType']" 
                                             message-store="ccsJdbcMessageStore" 
                                             send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" 
                                              group-timeout-expression="#{aggregateGroupTimeoutValue}"
                                             expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
                                             expire-groups-upon-timeout="true" 
                                             release-strategy-expression="#{aggregateReleaseStrategyExpressionValue}"
                                             ref="ccsAggregatorBean" 
                                             method="processMessage"  
                                             auto-startup="true"/>
```

We occasionally notice some messages pending in INT_MESSAGE table as there are not supposed to be any pending after aggregation, could u suggest what could be the issue with it? Please note that I don't see any pending messages in either INT_MSG_GROUP or INT_GROUP_TO_MSG tables, we need to fix this issue where some messages are not aggregated.

Note:

We use group-timeout expression which expires the group based on a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

When message group is expired, the `JdbcMessageStore` performs these update queries:

```
public void removeMessageGroup(Object groupId) {
    String groupKey = getKey(groupId);

    this.jdbcTemplate.update(getQuery(Query.DELETE_MESSAGES_FROM_GROUP), groupKey, this.region, this.region);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Removing relationships for the group with group key=" + groupKey);
    }
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(getQuery(Query.REMOVE_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE_JOIN), groupKey, this.region);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Deleting messages with group key=" + groupKey);
    }

    this.jdbcTemplate.update(getQuery(Query.DELETE_MESSAGE_GROUP), groupKey, this.region);
}
```

So, the first one belongs to the mentioned `INT_MESSAGE`:

```
DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in 
(SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ? and REGION = ?) and REGION = ?
```

Then as you notices an `INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE` is cleaned from the group and so on for the `INT_MESSAGE_GROUP`.

Therefore it is not clear how those messages can be stale, if they belong to any group you are cleaning from the store.

On the other hand the `INT_MESSAGE` table is used for other scenarios where plain message manipulation is necessary (no group correlation). See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-store. And a `MessageStore` interface. Therefore those messages could be stored from some other endpoints and they are not related to the mentioned aggregator anyway. For example Claim Check pattern uses a plain `MessageStore` abstraction.

Comment: That's interesting why I see messages pending, we only handle specific groups and there is no way we handle other groups in our application yet we see staled messages, the problem is we can't tell what group these messages belong to

Comment: Do you find anything odd with the configuration?

Comment: I do not. If you still think that you don't use the same `JdbcMessageStore` somewhere else, I would suggest to share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce.

Comment: May I know how I can do that?

Comment: You create a repo in your GitHub account and share the link over here. It would be also great to have some readme in that project to let us know how to run and reproduce.

Comment: this app is currently in production, and I am not able to reproduce this in any way, the messages pending are from 6 months ago..weird

Comment: `6 months ago` - perhaps you had some bug before or used an old version of the library. Why just not clean it up and move on with actual data?

Comment: that makes sense about 6 months ago we updated spring integration version from 4.2.3 to 5.1.4, could it have fixed the issue?

Comment: How so? That's indeed a jump with a couple missed versions in between. The framework cannot control the data for you. It's really better to review your DBA management and work out a data migration procedure.

Comment: cause I don't see any staled messages in the last 6 months, I don't get when you said couple of missed versions?

Comment: There were a `4.3.x` and `5.0.x` generations in between. You said you upgraded from `4.2.x` to `5.1.x` directly. I won't mind we had fixed something in those versions, but all of them are out of support for a while.

Comment: yes indeed it's a big jump in versions, should we watch and see if it happens again?

Comment: Well, this is the first time I hear about this problem: still not clear what is the cause. So, probably we can be sure that everything works OK so far if there is no manual interference into DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246208/discussion-between-satish-kumar-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: I don't do chats over here. Just comment whatever you'd like and I'll come back to you whenever I can.